# Docker authentication without certificates and DNS

Tags: docker, authentication

My goal is to require a password from user who is trying `docker pull` from my local Docker registry. I guess he has to login first via `docker login`.

Our network does not have DNS server and only port 5000 (used for Docker registry) is available. According to [Deploy a registry server](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) it seems there is no other possibility of authentication than via DNS and a certificate authority. Is that true? Isn't it possible to have a basic (plaintext and unencrypted) authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Use nginx as reverse proxy and turn on basic auth on in.

```
upstream registry {
    server registry:5000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name registry.example.com;

    server_tokens off;

    auth_basic "Authentication Required";
    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd/file/here;

    client_max_body_size 2G;

    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://registry;
    }
}
```